# Importing multiple externan Javascript libraries

Tags: javascript, highcharts, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I need to import multiple JS files into iPython Notebook.

This seems to work, however it seems a bit ugly to me.

```
%%javascript
require.config({
  paths: {
      highcharts: 'http://localhost:3000/hicharts/js/highcharts'
  }
});
require.config({
  paths: {
      exporting: 'http://localhost:3000/hicharts/js/modules/exporting'
  }
});
```

I was sort of expecting this to have worked:

```
%%javascript
require.config({
  paths: {
      highcharts: 'http://localhost:3000/hicharts/js/highcharts',
      exporting: 'http://localhost:3000/hicharts/js/modules/exporting'
  }
});
```

Am I missing anything here, and does anyone know where its documented ? I can't seem to find much that discusses it.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
%%javascript
require.config({
  paths:[ 
    { highcharts: 'http://localhost:3000/hicharts/js/highcharts' },
    {  exporting: 'http://localhost:3000/hicharts/js/modules/exporting' }
]
});
```

I suspect it needs an array of objects, not a dictionary.